Which VNC use for Gnome or how to run Gnome on X2GO?
I used x2go with XFCE, but when moving due to the need for wayland for waydroid on gnome, it turned out that x2go does not support such modern shells, so the question arose, and on the Internet there are tons of VNC, half of which have the same problems as x2go, others only for Windows (and I have a Mac), and others are so rare that when something goes wrong there will be no one to ask. Even the answer to how to run waydroid will be very helpful, since this is the root of the whole problem or running Gnome that works fine on x2go.
